# Creating a movie of histograms in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I used below code to create two movies of histographs in Matlab:

```
h1 = figure
hold on
vid = VideoWriter('graph.avi');open(vid);
for t=1:time
figure(h1); 
cla
hist(eighsum(t,:),40)
currFrame = getframe(h1); 
writeVideo(vid,currFrame);
end
close(vid);
```

and

```
h2 = figure
hold on
video = VideoWriter('graphh.avi');open(video);
sizeclu = cell(1,size(clustersize,2));
for i = 1:numel(sizeclu)
sizeclu{i} = [clustersize{:,i}];
figure(h2);
cla
hist(sizeclu{i})
currFrame = getframe(h2); % gets only figure 2
writeVideo(video,currFrame);
end
close(video);
```

I want numbers below 1 don't be shown in the histogram. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
[counts,centers] = hist(eighsum(t,:),40);
centers(counts < 1) = [];
counts(counts < 1) = [];
bar(centers,counts);
```

Comment: It shows zero instead of numbers smaller than 1. But I want numbers smaller than 1 don't be shown in the movie